# How to retrieve a Json file in swift

Tags: swift

I try to program in swift and I have to retrieve a json file from internet. I have the link url but I really do not know how to do it. I used the link http://www.learnswiftonline.com/mini-tutorials/how-to-download-and-read-json/. But I have errors on **let urlRequest** and  **let session**. Can you help me please.

my code is:

```
let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=mobilierstationnementparis2011&facet=info&facet=libelle")!
let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in

    let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
    let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

    if (statusCode == 200) {
        print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")
    }
}
```

I used the code of this website: http://www.learnswiftonline.com/mini-tutorials/how-to-download-and-read-json/

Comment: you should provide some code.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need to update the code for Swift 3

```
let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in

    let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
    let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

    if (statusCode == 200) {
        print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")
    }
}

task.resume()
```